# How to make and well position HTML custom list marker

Tags: html, css

I have this inline unordered list with custom markers.

```css
ul {
      list-style: none; /* Remove default bullets */
  }
  ul li {
      display:inline;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
  ul li::before {
      content: "\2022";  /* Add content: \2022 is the CSS Code/unicode for a bullet */
      font-weight: bold; /* If you want it to be bold */
      font-size: 30px;
      display: inline-block; /* Needed to add space between the bullet and the text */
      width: 1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
      margin-left: -1em; /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
  }
  ul .marker-info::before {
      color: rgb(116, 6, 206); /* Change the color */
  }
  ul .marker-primary::before {
      color: rgb(79, 66, 252); /* Change the color */
  }
  ul .marker-danger::before {
      color: rgb(253, 49, 49); /* Change the color */
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="marker-primary">Leaf</li>
    <li class="marker-info">Intermediate</li>
    <li class="marker-danger">Root</li>
</ul>
```

But as you can see here in the output the marker position is not aligned with text. And the distance between `list-item` is not same. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes (there are others ways too of course), and here you go :

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}
ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -50%;
}
ul .marker-info::before {
  color: rgb(116, 6, 206); 
}
ul .marker-primary::before {
  color: rgb(79, 66, 252); 
}
ul .marker-danger::before {
  color: rgb(253, 49, 49); 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="marker-primary">Leaf</li>
  <li class="marker-info">Intermediate</li>
  <li class="marker-danger">Root</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused because the text within the list is not vertically aligned in the middle.
One of the easy solutions is to use Flexbox. See the comments within CSS:

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
  }
  ul li {
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      display: inline-flex; /* adds flexbox to vertical align text */
      align-items: center; /* vertically align the text within the flexbox */
  }
  ul li::before {
      content: "\2022";
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
      width: 1em;
      margin-left: -1em;
  }
  ul .marker-info::before {
      color: rgb(116, 6, 206);
  }
  ul .marker-primary::before {
      color: rgb(79, 66, 252);
  }
  ul .marker-danger::before {
      color: rgb(253, 49, 49);
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="marker-primary">Leaf</li>
    <li class="marker-info">Intermediate</li>
    <li class="marker-danger">Root</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

If I have understood well the question, for vertical aligning the marker is `vertical-align:middle;` in `ul li::before` section. What do you mean by the distance between list-item is not the same?

Comment: Have you even tried this before posting it? It does not work because the list-bullet is already vertically centered. also `vertical-align: middle` does align within the element but within the line-height. The issue is caused because the line-height is not the same as the elements height.

Comment: Yes, I have tried on jsfiddle already yesterday. I know about line-height and with  this example was set good. Here you go with the example working: https://jsfiddle.net/2xzbqc8r/

Comment: your fiddle uses flexbox at the top(`ul li`) from my solution. Thats why it is working in your fiddle. remove my lines and you see that your solution fails: https://jsfiddle.net/osarx01w/